# Convert a string that has a list with strings

Tags: python, string, list

In python I have a function that's calling an api, when I check the result type by doing:
`type(desi)`
result:
`<class 'str'>`
When I do:
`print(desi)`
result:
`["word"]`

I want to convert that result to a list type. I am not sure why the API is returning a string with a list inside it instead of just a list.

Comment: Please edit your question to show more of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can parse this string to a list with the builtin `json` module.

```py
import json

desi = '["word"]'

print(type(desi))
print(desi)

desi2 = json.loads(desi)

print(type(desi2))
print(desi2)
```

output:

```py
<class 'str'>
["word"]
<class 'list'>
['word']
```

An HTTP request is just text, whatever library you're using to interact with it just hasn't parsed the text for you.